# How to optimize code for deleting n position in all the lists from a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I search the site for this issue and I found many posts about deleting specific values from list of lists.

However, this doesn't answer my question.

Lets have:

```
mylist=[[1,2,3,4],[100,374,283,738]]
```

Now, in my mind the two lists are linked. List 1 number items: 1, 2, 3, 4,... and list 2 a feature of these items (for example prices: $100, $374, etc).

Now, I want to delete from the list the elements (number and price) if list2 is hihger of a certain value (for example if an item is too expensive, more than $300)

I have been trying and I got this:

```
n=0 # counter for position in the list
for i in mylist[1]:
    if i>300:
        for j in mylist:
            del j[n]
    n=n+1
```

result:

```
[[1,3],[100,283]]
```

This actually works. It looks not too efficient: I have to access the list several times and I have to create new variables. Too many loops.

Since lists can use comprehension lists I was wonder if there is a more efficient and elegant method getting same result

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `zip` with a filtering generator expression:

```
>>> mylist = [[1,2,3,4], [100,374,283,738]]
>>> mylist[:] = list(map(list, zip(*((a,b) for a,b in zip(*mylist) if b<300))))
>>> mylist
[[1, 3], [100, 283]]
```

Note that this keeps the old `mylist` pointer, to mimic the way your code modifies the original list.

Comment: I impressed about all the comments with answers. All are good ways to get the same result, and all much better than the way I proposed. I voted up all of them. However, this way, Is exactly what I was looking. First, because it seems very efficient and returns the same list modified. I am not understanding it 100%, but I will work on that.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're trying to have a mapping from the elements of mylist[0] to the elements of mylist[1]. If so, I would suggest using a dictionary. Moving your data into one, your script might look like this:

```
mydict = { 1: 100, 2: 374, 3: 283, 4: 738 }

mykeys = list(mydict.keys())
for key in mykeys():
    if dict[key] > 300:
        del dict[key]
```

That's a little verbose, and we have to make copy the keys into a list because we can't modify a dictionary while looping over its keys. However, there is a short one-liner alternative of the type you may be looking for.

Comprehensions can also be used with dictionaries. For this example, it would look like:

```
mydict = { k: mydict[k] for k in mydict.keys() if mydict[k] <= 300 }
```

Edit:
There were some syntax issues in my original answer, but the corrected snippets should work.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're only trying to check price, let's go ahead and just make a simple loop:

```
mylist=[[1,2,3,4],[100,374,283,738]]
print [item for item in zip(*mylist) if item[1] <= 300]
```

Answer (score 1):

If `numpy` is available for you to use, you can try the following code:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> mylist=[[1,2,3,4],[100,374,283,738]]
>>> arr = np.array(mylist)
>>> price = np.array(mylist[1])
>>> np.delete(arr, np.where(price>=300), 1).tolist()
[[1, 3], [100, 283]]
```